# How I can redo foreach expression into stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

So, I have function:

```
public static int getMultiSum(List<Test> testList){
    int sum = 0;
    for(Test test : testList){
        sum += test.length * test.width;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

So, how I can use stream API for this function?

Comment: I'm not great with streams, but I think you'd `map` test to `test.length * test.width` then use `sum()` to finish up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `mapToInt` to convert the `Test` stream to an `IntStream`, then use the reduction method `sum`.

```java
    public static int getMultiSum(List<Test> testList){
        return testList.stream().mapToInt(t -> t.length * t.width).sum();
    }
```